# Parallel port usage on Windows

Tags: windows, parallel-port, lpt

I'm planning to drive a [Noritake VFD GU256x64D-3900](http://www.noritake-itron.com/newweb/gvfd/catagory/comp.asp#GU256x64D-3900) through parallel port from a Windows 10 PC.

For that purpose I started investigating ways to use parallel ports on Windows.
I found some documentations about [Communications Resource Handles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363198(v=vs.85).aspx) and [Client Interfaces to System-Supplied Parallel Drivers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543926(v=vs.85).aspx).

It seems that a lot of people toying around with parallel ports on Windows are using a specific driver named [inpout32](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/inpout32/) to access the parallel port registers. Ideally I would like to avoid using it in the final solution and stick to Microsoft's driver, if at all possible. Though it's proving useful to test my parallel port notably through [LPT Test Utility](http://www.xlentelectronics.nl/LPTTest/LPTTestUtilx64r.htm) using the suggested circuit.

Now using the sample code provided [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664463/writefile-to-parallel-port-hangs), that WriteFile function hangs no matter what I set my Ack and Busy pins to using the [LPT Test Utility circuit](http://www.xlentelectronics.nl/LPTTest/LPTTest_schematic.htm). It hangs even if I try writing a single byte of data. However calling WriteFile turns on Strobe and Linefeed LEDs.

Through LPT Test Utility I get the following results:

- I can control all data LEDs
- I can read all status controlled through DIP switch (Error, Select, Paper out, Busy, Ack)
- Init and Select Printer LEDs are working fine
- Strobe and Linefeed LEDS can only be turned on and off together. If I untick either of them both LEDs turn off.

I believe the parallel port I'm testing that with is in ECP mode.

Since that Noritake VFD only connect to D0-D7, /WR (strobe), Busy and grounds I'm concerned I might get that same hang behavior once I connect the display.

I have yet to start checking various functionality of the Microsoft driver, apparently accessible through DeviceIoControl, to see how and if I could influence the workings of my port.

Is there anyone out there with knowledge and possibly working code samples for such specific usage a parallel port on Windows?

Comment: There is no "Microsoft driver" that's going to be useful to you.  If you want to run that LPT test utility then you'll actually have to use a printer that uses a Centronics connector, so the ACK signal gets used, they've gone the way of the dodo a long time ago.  Check with the vendor for recommended solutions to use this board, but pretty likely that they expect you to use inpout32.

Comment: LPT Test Utility is working. It does not need a printer.